# Custom type descriptions on hover

Tags: python, python-typing

In my codebase, I have a lot of objects which are structured numpy arrays. I want to type annotate them for better readability and maintenance. However, I'm struggling to figure out a pythonic way of doing this. A way which is IDE/code-editor friendly and user-friendly at the same time. Here is how my "objects" are like:

```
import numpy as np

def init_ray():
    ray_struct = np.zeros(1, dtype=ray_fields)
    return ray_struct
```

where

```
ray_fields = np.dtype(
    [
        ("x", "f8"),
        ("y", "f8"),
        ("z", "f8"),
        ("vx", "f8"),
        ("vy", "f8"),
        ("vz", "f8"),
    ]
)
```

And a "ray" is initialized as

```
ray = init_ray()
```

The functionality I desire is that my IDE recognizes which type of structured numpy array `ray` is, because there are other "objects" as well like

```
cell = init_cell()
```

and so on, which look like same: a custom datatype defined using `numpy.dtype`, which is called by an initializer function which returns an `NDArray`, but I would like exactly which `NDArray`.

For now, I have implemented this hack where I have defined a dummy classes. So:

```
class Ray:
    """A numpy array containing ray data.
    
    Fields
    ------
    x: float64
        x-coordinate of ray origin.
    y: float64
        y-coordinate of ray origin.
    z: float64
        z-coordinate of ray origin.
    vx: float64
        x-component of ray direction.
    vy: float64
        y-component of ray direction.
    vz: float64
        z-component of ray direction."""

    pass
```

and I annotate my function with a return type:

```
def init_ray() -> Ray:
    ray_struct = np.zeros(1, dtype=ray_fields)
    return ray_struct
```

But this is probably not a good idea (or is it fine? Pycharm does not like it because when access a field by `[]`, it says I don't have a `__getitem__` method defined so it is an invalid operation. So I am gathering that even if it works, it probably is not the correct or pythonic way. I have also looked into `TypeVar` and `NewType`, but I don't know if I can put all my metadata (field information) on just the hover feature of the IDE. I mean right now, just hover over `ray` and you'll see it is of type `Ray` and you'll its type definition through the docstring. The main problem is with `TypeVar` is that I cannot have docstrings for variables in python, otherwise that would have been perfect.